# What is the best way to do a sub query for a max on 2 columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have three tables.

- `Sales_Header`: Sales_Ordernum, Customer, Total Cost
- `Sales Details`: Sales_Ordernum, Product_number, Sales_Cost
- `Product`: Product_number, Product_name, Product_height, Product_length

For delivery purposes I want to return the maximum value of `Product_height` and `Product_length` could be from multiple products in the product table.

So I would like the output to look like this:

```
Sales_Ordernum,
Customer,
Max_Productheight,
Max_Productlength
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join and aggregate:

```
select sh.sales_ordernum, sh.customer, 
    max(p.product_height) as max_product_height,
    max(p.product_length) as max_product_length
from sales_header sh
inner join sales_details sd on sd.sales_ordernum = sh.sales_ordernum
inner join product p on p.product_number = sd.product_number
group by sh.sales_ordernum, sh.customer
```